# how to play a base64 video in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am trying to play a base64 video in react native but I could not find any solution. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, not encryption.

Comment: I think that the best solution is to create a blob and pass to react-native-video the blob uri.

Comment: can you please provide any reference? @ Paolo Dell'Aguzzo

Comment: not working this solution please explain further.

Comment: any luck @Rajat ??